# SIGSEGV when using inherited QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, qwidget, qgraphicsscene

I'm trying to inherit from a QGraphicsScene but somehow that crashes my program when I try to use it. I guess somewhere I'm missing a small thing, but I couldn't figure it out. Here is a minimal example of what I tried so far:

**myscene.h**

```
#ifndef MYSCENE_H
#define MYSCENE_H

#include <QGraphicsScene>

class MyScene : public QGraphicsScene
{
    Q_OBJECT

    QPen* pen_bg;

public:
    explicit MyScene(QObject* parent=nullptr);
    ~MyScene();
};

#endif // MYSCENE_H
```

**myscene.cpp**

```
#include "myscene.h"

MyScene::MyScene(QObject* parent):
    QGraphicsScene (parent)
{
    pen_bg = new QPen(Qt::blue);
}

MyScene::~MyScene()
{
    delete pen_bg;
}
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "myscene.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{    
    MyScene *m_scene = new MyScene(this);
    ui->graphicView->setScene(m_scene);
}
```

As soon as I call the `setScene(m_scene)` function, the program crashes with a SIGSEGV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the UI file, you need to first call `setupUi()` before using it, otherwise the UI elements are not initialized. See docs: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-a-ui-file.html

Add

```
 ui->setupUi(this);
```

to your `MainWindow` constructor.